# What is $f(18)$ if $f$ is odd with period $5$ and $f(-8)=1$?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I have the following problem:

> The function $f(x)$ is odd, its period is $5$ and $f(-8) = 1$. What is $f(18)$?

So, $f(-8) = f(-8 + 5) = 1$. I also know that you could replace $(-8)$ with $(-3)$ and still get the same result of $1$.

I'm just learning about periods. My grasp on it still isn't very impressive. I understand that even functions are symmetric about the y axis and odd functions are symmetric about the origin, but my brain just isn't making the connection on this one.

Please help!

-Jon

Comment: Well, "odd" implies that $f(8)=-f(-8)=-1$.  Does that help?

Comment: Don't think so much about the geometric properties that the graphs of odd functions have - think about odd meaning $$f(-x) = -f(x)$$

Comment: Thank you for the replies so far,

I've been thinking about it the meaning of the odd function, but something in my brain just isn't connecting the dots. I'm gonna keep trying in earnest in the meantime, but there's some logical link that's hiding from me.

I hate to ask this much more, especially given that I'm new, but could someone provide a similar problem with the methods and the answer so that I can study it and apply the methods to my problem?

Thanks again,

-Jon

Comment: I've been thinking about what you said, lulu, and I think it does help a bit. Thanks, I'll keep thinking on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to thoroughly understand the definition of an odd function. A function is odd if $f(-x) = -f(x)$. Try to think of some examples of odd functions. For instance, $g(x) = x^3$ is odd by our definition. What does its graph look like? If we take the portion of the graph lying to the right of the $y$-axis and flip it over the $x$-axis, then flip it again over the $y$-axis, we get the other half of the graph. Try to think of some more examples. For instance, why is $\sin x$ odd? Why is $x^2$ not odd?

All told, now let's look at your problem. If your function $f$ is odd, and you are given the value of $f(-8)$, then by the definition of an odd function, $f(-8) = -f(8)$. Then, $-f(8) = 1$, so $f(8) = -1$. Since $f$ has period $5$, $f(8) = f(8 + 5) = f((8 + 5) + 5) = f(18) = -1$.

Comment: Eiff: Thanks for the hint! I knew I could reach -18 from -8, but my stupid brain couldn't quite put it together. Yeah, it would make sense to get to 18 from 8.

AOrtiz: Whoa, thanks for the solution! I was kinda wondering if the answer wasn't -1, but I just couldn't find the way to get there. This information will help me in the future, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** The function being odd means that
$$f(8) = -f(-8) = -1. $$

Furthermore, you know $f$ has a period of $5$. Can you reach $18$ by jumping periods of $5$ from $8$?

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I knew I could reach -18 from -8, but my stupid brain couldn't quite put it together. Yeah, it would make sense to get to 18 from 8.